# How to pass attribute value with double slash to a template

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

I am trying to develop a cookbook which is going to support both Windows and Linux platform. I am having some issue while working with a template. So, basically I am trying to put a shell script which will have a `export` command with a path. But I am not able to get the exact value on the shell script on the windows.

**Attribute:**

```
root_path = value_for_platform(
  'windows' => { 'default' => "D:\\" },
  'default' => '/opt'
)
xyz_path = value_for_platform(
  'windows' => { 'default' => "#{root_path}xyz_app\\tool\\bin\\xyz.bat" },
  'default' => "#{root_path}/xyz_app//tool//bin//xyz"
)
```

**Recipe:**

```
template File.join(root_path, '/tmp/xyz_path.sh') do
  source 'xyz_path.sh.erb'
  mode '0755'
  variables({
    :xyz_path => xyz_path
  })
end
```

**Template**

```
#!/bin/bash

export xyz_path = <%= @xyz_path %>
```

**Expectation on Windows**

```
#!/bin/bash

export xyz_path = D:\\xyz_app\\tool\\bin\\xyz.bat
```

**Reality on Windows**

```
#!/bin/bash

export xyz_path = D:\xyz_app\tool\bin\xyz.bat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 4 backslashes to get what you desire .

```
root_path = value_for_platform(
  'windows' => { 'default' => "D:\\\\" },
  'default' => '/opt'
)
xyz_path = value_for_platform(
  'windows' => { 'default' => "#{root_path}xyz_app\\\\tool\\\\bin\\\\xyz.bat" },
  'default' => "#{root_path}/xyz_app//tool//bin//xyz"
)
```

Since the backslash is the escape character the first backslash escapes the second one so you need to repeat this twice in order to get two backslashes in the output